# Azure Application Gateway exclude - inspection of nested request body property

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I need to exclude the inspection of a nested request body parameter in Azure Application Gateway. Using the Azure Portal, I've tried the following without success:

e.g. request body contents:

```json
{
  "aRootProperty": "value",
  "aRootContainer": {
    "aNestedProperty": "some-string-that-causes-false-positives"
  }
}
```

Azure Portal Exclusion config:

> Field: `Request Attribute Name`
>
> Operator: `Equals`
>
> Selector: `aNestedProperty`

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-waf-configuration) has a couple of examples but they're not very useful. Additionally, the docs don't really cover how the various Operators and the Selector work in practice.

With some testing, I found that I could use the `Contains` operator, but that's a bit more permissive than I'd like as any property that happens to contain the string "aNestedProperty" will be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

It's undocumented, but the `Selector` supports dot-notation for exclusion of nested properties.

So, the rule can be updated to the following for success (and it's not unnecessarily permissive!):

> Field: `Request Attribute Name`
>
> Operator: `Equals`
>
> Selector: `aRootContainer.aNestedProperty`

I've posted [this doc issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/90501) so that the docs are (hopefully) updated soon.